# "good" numbers and the measure of goodness

Tags: real-analysis

Let us define the measure of goodness for some positive number $x$ as follow :

$g_0 = x$ and $g_{n+1} = \{ g_n \} x$ and the goodness measure of the number $x$ is the smallest $n$ such that $0\leq g_n <1$ denoted $G(x)$.

For example  $G(\pi)=1 $ because $g_0 =\pi$ and $g_1 = (\pi-3 )* \pi \approx 0.444<1$, also $G(e) = 10$

We say a number is "good" number if $G(x)= \infty$.

My question : is there any "good" numbers ?!

I think there is(a gut feelings) nothing rigours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N\ge2$.
Then  $g_0\colon [N,N+1)\to [N,N+1)$ is a strictly increasing bijection and hence $g_1\colon [N,N+1)\to [0,N+1)$ is a strictly increasing bijection. Then we can find $[a_1,b_1)\subset [N,N+1)$ such that $g_1\colon [a_1,b_1)\to [N-1,N)$ is a strictly  increasing bijection.

Assume that for some $n$, we have found nested intervals
$$[a_n,b_n)\subset [a_{n-1},b_{n-1})\subset\cdots \subset [a_1,b_1)\subset [N,N+1)$$ such that $g_n\colon [a_n,b_n)\to [N-1,N)$ is a strictly increasing bijection. Then on the same interval, $g_{n+1}$ is a strictly increasing bijection to $[0,b_n)$. As $b_n>a_n>N$, it follows that we can find some subinterval $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1})\subset [a_n,b_n)$ such that $g_{n+1}\colon [a_{n+1},b_{n+1})\to [N-1,N)$ is a strictly increasing bijection.

By the nested  intervals, the limit $a:=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists. As $a\in [a_n,b_n)$ for all $n$, we conclude that $g_n(a)\ge N-1$ for all $n$ (and even stronger $g_0(a)\ge N$).

We conclude that $G(a)=\infty$.